# MariaDB FULLTEXT index on more than 16 columns?

Tags: mariadb, full-text-indexing, database-indexes, navicat

The [MariaDB documentation for InnoDB Limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-limitations/) states that:

> A multicolumn index on InnoDB can use a maximum of 16 columns. If you
>   attempt to create a multicolumn index that uses more than 16 columns,
>   MariaDB returns an Error 1070.

Is there any way around this limitation, so that I may create a fulltext index on 17 columns?

I am using MariaDB 10.1.37 and Navicat 11.2.11 Standard. When I try to add a fulltext index on 17 columns I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The multicolumn limitation doesn't apply for FULLTEXT Indexes.
FULLTEXT Indexes have a maximum of 32 parts in InnoDB.

Comment: Could you link to a reference for this please?

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation, I would recommend having an extra column that is the combination of all the text columns you want to search on.

Comment: I considered this, but I also need to rank results with relevancy weighted differently on some columns. Maybe I can combine the columns I want with higher weights into one column, and the lower weight columns into another column. Although I know this will give different results, it might be sufficient.